# Getting matrix dimension error while modulating audio waveform on matlab

Tags: matlab, modulation

I am getting the matrix dimension error for the following code. What I am trying to do below is modulation of an audio waveform but I could not get passed the error I specified.  I have checked the length of the sample.wav and adjusted time axis(t) accordingly but I must have done something wrong. I appreciate if anyone could help. Thanks in advance!.

```
 function [sm]= modulation(ss,fc,mtype)
ss= audioread('C:\Users\furka\Documents\MATLAB\sample.wav');     %audio waveform to be modulated is loaded.
plot(ss)
length(ss)
t=linspace(0,3e6,3161538);
fc= input('Carrier Frequency=');            %carrier frequency will be determined by the user


mtype= menu('Modulation type?','dsb','dsbsc','ssb','fm');           %modulation type will be determined by the user
%fs=44100;                                   %sampling frequency is determined for common audio waveform.(44.1kHz)
%t= 0:1/fs:(2e-5)-1/fs;

if mtype==1 
    ka= 0.7;
    sm= ss.*(1+ka*cos(2*pi*fc*t));
    plot(t,sm)

    elseif mtype==2                         %if doublesideband suppress carrier is selected the statements below will be carried out.

    y = ss.*cos(2*pi*fc*t);
    plot(y)
    % sm = fftshift(fft(abs(y)));
  %  frequency_axis= (-fs/2):(fs/length(sm)):(fs/2-fs/length(sm));
    %plot(frequency_axis,sm)

    elseif mtype==3
    sm=0.5*[ss.*cos(2*pi*fc*t)-hilbert(ss).*sin(2*pi*fc*t)];
    plot(t,sm)

    elseif mtype==4
     kf=0.7;            %frequency sensitivity.
    sm= cos(2*pi*fc*t+2*pi*kf*int(ss,t,0,t));
    plot(t,sm)
end
end
```

Comment: Can you share `sample.wav` or use a wav file that we all have?  Also what is the exact error and where does it occur?

Comment: Here is the sample.wav:https://ufile.io/m5mtu .The error occurs during every modulation statement so that the dimensions of t and sample do not match.

Comment: I have uploaded the code itself as well .
https://ufile.io/ht0zb
The exact error is :
Error using  .* 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in Assgn_Modulation (line 16)
    sm= ss.*(1+ka*cos(2*pi*fc*t));
Error using  .* 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in Assgn_Modulation (line 21)
    y = ss.*cos(2*pi*fc*t);
Error using  .* 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in Assgn_Modulation (line 28)
    sm=0.5*[ss.*cos(2*pi*fc*t)-hilbert(ss).*sin(2*pi*fc*t)];
I guess all of them are caused by the same mistake.

Comment: I would say you need to use both outputs from `audioread`.  The first is the sound the second is the frequency.  `[ss, Fs] = audioread(...)` then length of sound `total = length(ss) / Fs`.  Then `t = linspace(0, total, length(ss));`

Comment: I am glad for your help  but still getting the same error , I have edited my code the way you expressed.


 `function [sm]= modulation(ss,fc,mtype)
[ss,Fs]= audioread('C:\Users\furka\Documents\MATLAB\sample.wav');     %audio waveform to be modulated is loaded.
Fs                          %sampling frequency is 44.1kHz  for  audio waveform.


total=length(ss)/ Fs
t=linspace(0,total,length(ss));
fc= input('Carrier Frequency=');            %carrier frequency will be determined by the user`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't access the link provided for the sound file but a time length of 3e6 seconds seems like a really long sound.  I figure that's something around 30 days long.

Using the `handel.mat` example provided by MathWorks I get this.

```
load handel.mat
audiowrite('sample.wav', y, Fs);
[ss, Fs] = audioread('sample.wav');

t = linspace(0, length(ss) / Fs, length(ss));
t = t'; % this is important to match ss <-- this is your matrix dimension error I think
fc = 2000;
ka = 0.7
sm = ss .* (1 + ka * cos(2 * pi * fc * t));
```

The error of mismatched dimensions comes from `linspace` output being a row vector and `audioread` output being a column vector.  Transpose one or the other.  In my case: `t = t'`

Comment: After taking transpose , modulation worked just fine  . Thanks very much . You have been very helpful. 
By the way the sound file is solely 1:11 minute long. I have taken 3e6 due to the sketched waveform's x axis `plot(ss)`.
Uploaded to another source https://vocaroo.com/i/s1ClXAtgG9j1